# Does Magento 2 have namespace length restriction?

Tags: magento2, module, xml

Is there any restriction in Magento 2 with the length of the Vendor name for minimum of 3 ?

I have a vendor say: AB_Test

after upgrading the module, i get:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid Document 
Element 'add', attribute 'title': [facet 'minLength'] The value 'AB' has a length of '2'; this underruns the allowed minimum length of '3'.
Line: 26
```

And other modules which are under 'AB' works fine.

Is it any xml issue or is it a restriction?

I do not get proper solution over the net for this issue.

**UPDATE:**

menu.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
<menu> 
    <add id="HM_Brand::brand" title="Brand" module="HM_Brand" sortOrder="40" resource="HM_Brand::brand" parent="HM_All::hm_all"/>  
    <add id="HM_Brand::brand_new" title="Add New Brand" module="HM_Brand" sortOrder="10" parent="HM_Brand::brand" action="hmbrand/brand/new" resource="HM_Brand::brand"/> 
    <add id="HM_Brand::brand_manage" title="Manage Brands" module="HM_Brand" sortOrder="20" parent="HM_Brand::brand" action="hmbrand/brand/index" resource="HM_Brand::brand"/>
    <add id="HM_Brand::brand_group_manage" title="Manage Groups" module="HM_Brand" sortOrder="40" parent="HM_Brand::brand" action="hmbrand/group/index" resource="HM_Brand::group"/> 
    <add id="HM_Brand::configuration" title="Settings" module="HM_Brand" sortOrder="50"
        parent="HM_Brand::brand" action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/hmbrand" resource="HM_Brand::config_brand"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: **Invalid document** means there some xml issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an XML restriction in your `menu.xml`.

Indeed, according to the `menu.xsd` validation schema there are several restrictions to the attributes of the `add` element, in your case:

```
<xs:simpleType name="typeTitle">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            Item title attribute minimal length 3 symbol
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="3" />
        <xs:maxLength value="50" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The title length must be between 3 and 50 characters

Comment: I have updated menu.xml in my question, since i have anywhere not used or set the min lenght, i guess its set in Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd !!!

Comment: @SachinS yes that's correct

Comment: So suggested way is we have to give min 3 length in our namespace since we cannot change the core file

Comment: @SachinS yup 100% correct